# How to ESLint files opened in Editor in Attached Docker container in VS Code?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, eslint

I switched to Development in a Docker container yesterday and it's working well overall.

One thing I am missing is Visual Highlighting of ESLint messages.

- Running `pnpm run lint` in my container yields (this is good)

  193:6  Warning: React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'state.editingRecord' and 'state.originalRecord'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
- Opening the file in the Editor does not give a visual hint that there is a problem in line 193

[image]

Expected behavior: `[]` should be underlined. Hovering over it should give the message `193:6 Warning: React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'state.editingRecord' and 'state.originalRecord'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.

Visual Highlighting works when working outside of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install [the ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) in the container. The extension page in the Extension View will have a button to "Install in Container <container name>". Like this:

[image]